# Can I add search plug-in to DataTable on fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I use DataTables 1.10.6 (https://datatables.net/) on ASP.NET MVC project.
In JavaScript I initialize DataTable:

```
var tableApiObj = $('#tableSelector').DataTable({
                'paging': false,
                'dom': 'ti',
                "order": [[3, 'desc']],
                "columns": columnsConfig,
                initComplete: dataTableInitComplete
            })
```

Can I add search plug-in (like [here](https://www.datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search#Example)) using `tableApiObj`?

Comment: You should be able to .... may or may not require re-initializing plugin though. What have you tried?

Comment: I try to:
`tableApiObj.ext.search.push(function(){ *** });` but `TypeError: tableApiObj.ext is undefined`.